# Strange bug in an answer of mine

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, score

Check out [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-string/4031040#4031040)

It supposedly has a score of +1, but when I click on the detailed reputation I see 0 up and 1 down votes. No positive or negative reputation has been [awarded to my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342852?tab=reputationhistory) from this question.

Comment: I think @org.life.java had a similar problem recently, @Marc Gravell (or one of the other mods) fixed it - but I cant find the exact link now. It might show in their activity history.

Comment: It appears to be fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The post scores are denormalized so they can be temporarily off at times. Casting a vote causes a sync, as well as our daily normalization scripts.